# "Unpacking" macro arguments

Tags: c, c99

I have the following macro:

```
#define HEX 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00

#define BITS 0x01

#define ADD_FLAGS(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) \
        a, b | BITS, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

I use this somewhere to create a byte array `{ADD_FLAGS(HEX)}`. This doesn't work. `HEX` is interpreted as a single argument to `ADD_FLAGS` and I get errors that there are too few arguments.

```
const myStructure Table[ENTRY_COUNT] =                   
{
   /* Entity Index 0 */
   {
      <some structure fields>,
      ADD_FLAGS(HEX),     // 8-byte array
      <more structure fields>
   }
}
```

I have also tried the following variants, but no success:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define ADD_FL(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) \
        a, b | BITS, c, d, e, f, g, h
#define ADD_FLAGS(...) ADD_FL EXPAND((__VA_ARGS__))

##################### other variant
#define ADD_FLAGS(...) EXPAND(ADD_FL (__VA_ARGS__))
```

I am using C99 and three different compilers, so any answer has to be standards compliant, otherwise there is surely going to be a comiler that's not working (I am using armclang, ghs and tasking).

Comment: Is there a reason to keep them as macros instead of making proper functions (or function templates) out of them?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The only requirements are: HEX is a compile definition that gets passed to the compiler. BITS doesn't need to be a macro but the value depends on compile definitions. The array ends up in a const structure.

Comment: Can you show the target structure and how you would like to have used the macros? It helps to see what the end result should be. I see that Staz has made a non-macro answer below. If that doesn't do the trick, could you comment under that answer and describe in what way it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory "avoid macros" aside, you just need to wrap `ADD_FLAGS` in another macro.

Rename it to something else, e.g. `ADD_FLAGS_`, and add

```
#define ADD_FLAGS(...) ADD_FLAGS_(__VA_ARGS__)
```

---

This works in GCC and Clang. In MSVC this works with the new preprocessor only (`/Zc:preprocessor` flag).

Not sure how to do it with the old MSVC preprocessor, but since it's notoriously buggy, I'd avoid supporting it if possible.

Comment: The "old MSVC" was (is) staunchly pre-C99. `__VA_ARGS__` is a C99 feature.

Comment: @mlp The old preprocessor does support `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: This answer works for me for tasking compiler but I have trouble getting it to work with armclang (still complaining about to few arguments, so the evaluation order seems to be different). Any insights on that since you state it works with clang.

Comment: @kutschkem Hmm, works [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zeM73b1cM).

Comment: I'll accept the answer since it seems to work for most compilers but will look for a different solution outside of macros, I guess. Seems like I am running into compiler-specific issues :-( maybe keil implementation of armclang has differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use macros sparingly. Here's an example snippet which does exactly what the macro is doing but it's a bit more reasonable in my opinion.

```
template<typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto add_flags(Ts && ... args){
     std::array flags{std::forward<Ts>(args)...};
     constexpr int bits = 0x01;
     // flags[some_idx] |= bits;
     return flags;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with what language variant I am using. Turns out I am using C99, not even actually C++. Does this affect your answer?

Comment: @kutschkem Well, C and C++ are two *different* languages and the code shown here is written in C++, not C. Please remember to add *only* the appropriate tags the next time you'll post a question.